# Changing my program's icon in DEV-C++ 5.11 (Win32 GUI mode)

Tags: icons, dev-c++

I'm learning to use DEV-C++ 5.11, hoping to make a program I have in mind.
Before I go any further, I would like to change the icon for the resulting program, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's what I did:

1. I start a new project (File - New - Project - Windows
   Application) and name it "test". This creates a generic main.cpp
   file in the with the WndProc and WinMain functions in it.
2. I compile and run, it creates a program (test.exe) which does
   nothing but works.
3. I delete the .exe file.
4. I copy an icon file (test.ico) in the directory of the project.
5. I set the icon as the project icon. (Project - Project Options -
   General - Icon - Browse - Type - Win32 GUI)
6. I compile and run again, the resulting program works but still
   shows that generic icon (in the title bar, on the task bar, in the
   file explorer and the Alt+Tab selector).

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm running on Windows 7 and the .ico file is a valid icon file that I took from another program and renamed, for the sake of the test.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out!

I replaced the following two lines

wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); /* Load a standard icon */

wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); /* use the name "A" to use the project icon */

with

wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, "A");

wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, "A");

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project->Project Options->Browse for your downloaded icon-> Type->Win32 Console(not prefreably `Win32 GUI`)

```
//Change
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);/*Load a standard icon*/
wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);/* use the name "A" to use the project icon */
//To
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, "A");/*Load a standard icon*/
wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, "A");/* use the name "A" to use the project icon */
```